# Get file path from id android

Tags: android

I am using this code to get the paths of all videos in android

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] proj = {
                BaseColumns._ID
};

Cursor c = cr.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do
    {
        int id = c.getInt(0);
        Bitmap b = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
        Log.d("*****My Thumbnail*****", "onCreate bitmap " + b);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
    while( c.moveToNext() );
}         
c.close();
```

But I am getting some id number. I want the real uri of file or content uri. How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] proj = {
MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA
};
```

...

```
String ID = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID));
String  DATA_URI = Uri.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA)));
```

Comment: thanks.. I must have done more research before asking xD